# Using Browserify with Angular JS - - Passing a service into a Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

As the title suggests I've recently started a new project where I'm using Browserify (and Gulp) to concatenate my Angular JS files (and the Angular sourcefile) into a single file  - bundle.js.

I've decided to split my controllers, services and directives into separate files and then "require" them into my app.js file using Browserify like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    require('angular');

    var tabCtrl = require('./controllers/tabs'),
    dataService = require('./services/');

    angular.module("citiToolsApp", [])
        .service('dataService', ['$scope', dataService])
        .controller('TabController', ['$scope', tabCtrl]);
}());
```

However when I try to access my service - dataService - from within my Tab Controller like this:

```
module.exports = function($scope, tabController) {

    dataService.getPrograms(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });

};
```

I get an undefined error. I believe I need to pass dataService into the tabController but I'm unsure on the syntax to do this. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I've also added the contents of my service file for further detail:

```
module.exports = function($http) {

    this.getPrograms = function(callback) {
        $http.get('/programs')
            .then(callback);
    };

};
```

Comment: tabCtrl and dataService should both return their entire definition including the array annotation. I'm not saying this is the solution to your problem but I do think it is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would you mind replying with a code example to outline what you mean? It would really help. Sorry I'm a bit of a noob to Angular and Browserify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realised my own mistake. I needed to pass in $http rather than $scope. So instead of:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    require('angular');

    var tabCtrl = require('./controllers/tabs'),
    dataService = require('./services/');

    angular.module("citiToolsApp", [])
        .service('dataService', ['$scope', dataService])
        .controller('TabController', ['$scope', tabCtrl]);
}());
```

It should be:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    require('angular');

    var tabCtrl = require('./controllers/tabs'),
    dataService = require('./services/');

    angular.module("citiToolsApp", [])
        .service('dataService', ['$http', dataService])
        .controller('TabController', ['$scope', tabCtrl]);
}());
```